# Python: how to troubleshoot Fatal IO error

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, fatal-error

I have multithreaded GUI program that has different threads for GUI, plot, server and three clients. The problem I'm having is that sometimes when starting a second client (one already running) the program crashes and only gives "Fatal IO error: client killed" as error report.

Is there a way to code the program to do a memory dump that  I could use to analyze the problem?